# USB-C port became disabled

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave, usb

For some reason, one of my USB-C ports on my 2017 Macbook Pro 13in became disabled.  The power cable going into the USB-C port wasn't charging the machine, and a monitor also plugged into that port wasn't recognized.

Is there a way to "re-enable" a USB-C port, to tell the machine to stop ignoring the input?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a physical issue with the port (or cable?) AFAIK there's no way to disable or enable specific ports within macOS, so my guess is that either something got damaged or there's something stuck on the contacts. Go ahead and check System Information -> Thunderbolt and ensure that both the busses are showing up too.

Comment: ...and make an appointment with the Genius Bar. If a port just goes bad that is often the system board needing to be replaced.

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8475625